# TypeProviders and [<Generate>] type not defined

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am playing a little with type providers using DemoScripts from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/10/05/demo-scripts-from-the-f-3-0-build-talk.aspx and I am getting message which is really strange to me.

The type 'Generate' is not defined  BLABLA\Demo\MonsterMovieHouse\Library1\Netflix.fs   18  11  DataAndAnalysis

Google is not helping, and as far as I managed to get some logic explanation is that this is visual studio 11 beta and maybe that's the problem. I referenced typroviders and here is link of visual studio window for details.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/02/29/introducing-visual-f-3-0-beta.aspx), in Beta the `Generate` attribute was removed.

Comment: Oh it works fine when i delete generate. Tnx Brian (and John :-) )

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this reference:

```
System.Data.Services.Client.dll
```